# Python Pygame - How do I add a time counter for my game?

Tags: python, pygame

So I want to know how can I add a time counter for Pygame? Or what is the best way to add a time counter for a Pygame program. The time counter should start when Pygame is initialised and end when `inventory[coins] > 100:`
The time counter should be in the bottom right and in seconds.

```
import pygame, sys
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import *

#MAIN GAME

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))

#colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
brown = (153, 76, 0)
blue  = (0, 0, 255)
grey  = (192,192,192)

#game dimensions
tilesize = 20
mapwidth = 30
mapheight = 20

coins = 0
ship = 1
water = 2
rock = 3
movesMade = 4

#dictionary for texture of the map
textures = { #the transform function scales the photo to the tile size
    ship : pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('ship.png').convert_alpha(), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    water: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('water.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    rock: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('rock.png').convert_alpha(), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    coins: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('chest.png'), (tilesize, tilesize)),
    movesMade: pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))
    }

inventory = {
    coins: 0,
    movesMade: 0
    }

#image that will represent player
PLAYER = pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('player.png'), (tilesize, tilesize))

#position of the player
playerPos = [0,0]

resources = [coins, movesMade]

#utilise list comprehension to create grid
tilemap = [[water for w in range(mapwidth)] for h in range(mapheight)]

#set up display
displaysurf = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth*tilesize,mapheight*tilesize + 60))


invfont = pygame.font.Font('FreeSansBold.ttf', 18)

#loops through each row
for rw in range(mapheight):
    for cl in range(mapwidth):
        randomnumber = random.randint(0,15)
        if randomnumber == 0 or randomnumber == 1:
            tile = rock
        elif randomnumber == 2 or randomnumber == 3 :
            tile = ship
        else:
            tile = water
        #sets position in the grid
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

visit = {}
while True:
    #start = time.time()
    displaysurf.fill(black) #background color

    #user events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < mapwidth - 1:
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < mapheight -1:
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                pos = (playerPos[1], playerPos[0])
                if not pos in visit: # checks whether a tile has been used
                    visit[pos] = True 
                    currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                    if currentTile == rock:
                        inventory[movesMade] += 1
                        percent = 30 # coins are kept with a probability of 30 percent and will be lost by 70 percent
                        ran1 = random.randint(0,100) # random value in [0, 99]
                        if ran1 >= percent and inventory[coins] > 30:
                            inventory[coins] -= 30
                        else:
                            inventory[coins] += 20

                    elif currentTile == ship:
                        inventory[coins] += 10
                        inventory[movesMade] += 1

    #loops through each row 
    for row in range(mapheight):
        #loops through each column in row
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            displaysurf.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*tilesize,row*tilesize))

    displaysurf.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*tilesize,playerPos[1]*tilesize))

    placePosition = 10
    for item in resources:
        displaysurf.blit(textures[item],(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 30
        #text displays amount of coin
        textObj = invfont.render(str(inventory[item]), True, white, black)
        displaysurf.blit(textObj,(placePosition, mapheight*tilesize + 20))
        placePosition += 50

    if inventory[coins] > 100:
        break
    #end = time.time()
    pygame.display.update()

#final = (end)
#print(final)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html) and create a [`pygame.freetype.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font) obejct:

e.g.

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

pygame.init()
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
```

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the current time in milliseconds and set the start time, before the main loop:

```py
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
while True:

    # [...]
```

Calculate the elapsed time in every frame. To convert from milliseconds to seconds, the time difference has to be divided by 1000.
Render the time text to a surface by ([`font.render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render)). Note, `.render()` returns a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object and a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). The rectangle can be used to calculate the position of the text. In the following the text is placed at the bottom right, with a margin of 20 to the border of the window:

```py
while True:

    # [...]

    if inventory[coins] < 100:
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        delta_time_s = (current_time - start_time) // 1000

        text_surf, text_rect = font.render(str(delta_time_s), (255, 255, 255), size=30) 
        margin = 20       # margin to the window 
        size = (200, 200) # window size
        text_pos = (size[0] - text_rect.width - margin, size[1] - text_rect.height - margin)

        displaysurf.blit(text_surf, text_pos)
```

If you want to show the tenths of seconds, then the calculation of `delta_time_s` has to be changed:

```py
delta_time_s = (current_time - start_time) // 100 / 10
```